# How to change URL of pagination in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I click on the next link. It shows me the URL like

```
http://www.domainname.com/fj_messages/index/page:2
```

I want to change it like change this to

```
fj_messages/index/page:2
```

Like
message/inbox/2

Can I do like this?

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in this link:- http://www.sakic.net/blog/changing-cakephp-pagination-urls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gaioshin WTF.. That is the worst thing I've seen with regards to custom routes.

```
Router::connect('message/inbox/:page', array('controller' => 'fj_messages', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('page')));
```

Something like that should do it just the way you want.  Check out [routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration) for more information.

The page will be in `$this->params['page']` if I remember correctly.